# omit results starting with certain character

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring

I am trying to retrieve a list of names from a table where the surname does not start with z or Z using mysql. I tried combining substring with instr to accomplish this. Attempt below:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS CONCAT(FName," ",SName)
    FROM Names  
    WHERE SUBSTRING(
                    CONCAT(FName, ' ' ,SName),
                    INSTR(CONCAT(FName, ' ' ,SName), ' ') +1,
                    1) 
          <> 'z' 
    OR SUBSTRING(
                  CONCAT(FName, ' ' ,SName), 
                  INSTR(CONCAT(FName, ' ' ,SName), ' ') +1, 
                  1)
          <> 'Z' 
    ORDER BY SName
```

My attempt is returning results with z as the first letter of the surname. Can anyone explain why? Or if there is a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be much shortened with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS CONCAT(FName," ",SName)
FROM Names  
WHERE FName NOT LIKE 'z%' AND FName NOT LIKE 'Z%';
```

IIRC `LIKE` is case-sensitive since MySQL v5.6.x

I wouldn't write it like

```
...WHERE LOWER(FName) NOT LIKE 'z%';
```

since applying functions on columns prevent MySQL from using the index on the column (if one exists).

Comment: this is a lot easier thanks.  I see now a crucial mistake I made was using OR and not AND! Don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS CONCAT(FName," ",SName)
FROM Names
WHERE FName REGEXP '^[^z]';
```

Comment: I got no source at hand to back this up right now, but if you can use `like` instead of `regexp`, you should definitely use `like`, if you care about performance.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Regexp more worse by performance than like, but it so convenient!)  And in question nothing were mentioned about performance... and when i wrote this answer, i seen your answer, and decide to write another option)